# How to find the expectation of a Poisson process related variable

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes, poisson-process

Q) Let $X_k\sim \operatorname{Exp}(\lambda)$, $X_k$ are iid which represent the interarrival times of a Poisson process of mean rate $\lambda$. Let $Y_k$ be the arrival times of the events. Let $$Z = \sum_{k=1}^N e^{-(t-Y_k)}$$ where $Y_1<Y_2<\cdots< t$ i.e. $N(t)$ events have occurred in time $t$. Find $EZ, \operatorname{Var}(Z)$.

> I have two questions. Does the $EZ$ calculation below look right and is there a simpler way to find $\operatorname{Var}(Z)$ because the expressions I have are large?

$N(t)\sim \operatorname{Pois}(\lambda t)$ and $Y_k\sim \operatorname{Erlang}(k,\lambda)$ because $Y_k$ is the sum of iid exponential r.v's.

$$\begin{align}
EZ &= E[E[Z\mid N(t)]] \\
&= E\left[\sum_{k=1}^{N(t)} Ee^{-(t-Y_k)}\right] \\
&= E\left[\sum_{k=1}^{N(t)}\int_0^{\infty} e^{-(t-x)}\frac{\lambda^k x^{k-1}e^{-\lambda x}}{(k-1)!}dx \right] \\
&= E\left[\sum_{k=1}^{N(t)}\frac{\lambda^k e^{-t}}{(k-1)!} \int_0^\infty e^{(1-\lambda )x}x^{k-1}dx \right] \\
\end{align}
$$

In general,

$$\int_0^{\infty}e^{ax}x^n = (-a)^{-k-1}\Gamma(n+1)$$

Thus:
$$\begin{align}
EZ &= E\left[\sum_{k=1}^{N(t)}\frac{\lambda^k e^{-t}}{(k-1)!}\int_0^{\infty} e^{(1-\lambda )x}x^{k-1}dx \right] \\
&= E\left[\sum_{k=1}^{N(t)}\frac{\lambda^k e^{-t}}{(k-1)!} (\lambda - 1)^{-k}\Gamma(k)\right] \\
&= E\left[\sum_{k=1}^{N(t)}\left( \frac{\lambda}{\lambda-1}\right)^k e^{-t} \right] \\
&= e^{-t} E\left[ \frac{1-\left(\frac{\lambda}{\lambda-1}\right)^{N(t)+1}}{1-\frac{\lambda}{\lambda-1}} - 1 \right] \tag{1}\\
\end{align}
$$

Note that since $N(t)\sim \operatorname{Pois}(\lambda t)$:

$$
\begin{align}
E\left[ \left(\frac{\lambda}{\lambda-1}\right)^{N(t)+1} \right] &= \frac{e^{-\lambda}}{\lambda !}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{\lambda}{\lambda-1}\right)^{k+1}\times (\lambda t)^k\\
&= \frac{1}{(\lambda-1)(\lambda-1)!}.e^{-\lambda}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{\lambda ^2 t}{\lambda-1}\right)^k \\
&= \frac{e^{-\lambda}}{(\lambda-1)(\lambda-1)!}\times \frac{1}{1-\left(\frac{\lambda ^2 t}{\lambda-1}\right)} \tag{2}
\end{align}
$$

Plugging $(2)$ in $(1)$, we get $EZ$.

Comment: What is $N$? A random variable, or a constant integer?

Comment: @Math1000 $N(t)$ is the number of arrivals [of the Poisson process] up until time $t$. It is a $\text{Poisson}(\lambda t)$ random variable.

Answer (score 0):

Tried an approach that I thought would be simpler, but ended up with a bigger mess than I thought. Posting here in case someone can do something with it, but I'll probably delete it later...

$e^t Z = \sum_{k=1}^\infty e^{Y_k} \mathbf{1}_{\{Y_k \le t\}}$

By Tonelli's theorem, it suffices to compute $E[e^{Y_k} \mathbf{1}_{\{Y_k \le t\}}]$ and sum over $k$.

$$E[e^{Y_k} \mathbf{1}_{\{Y_k \le t\}} \mid N(t) = n] = E[e^{Y_k} \mid N(t) = n] \mathbf{1}_{\{k \le n\}}.$$

Conditioned on $N(t)=n$, the random variable $Y_k$ has the same distribution as the $k$th order statistic of $n$ i.i.d. $\text{Uniform}(0,1)$ random varaibles. (See Theorem 1.5 of [these notes](http://www.columbia.edu/~ks20/stochastic-I/stochastic-I-PP.pdf).) In particular, the [conditional distribution is $\text{Beta}(k, n+1-k)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic#Order_statistics_sampled_from_a_uniform_distribution). Thus the expectation we want can be evaluated using the [moment generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution#Moment_generating_function). We have
$$E[e^{Y_k} \mathbf{1}_{\{Y_k \le t\}} \mid N(t) = n]
=\mathbf{1}_{\{k \le n\}}
\left(1 + \sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{1}{j!} \prod_{r=0}^{j-1}\frac{k+r}{n+1+r}\right) \tag{1}$$

\begin{align}
E[e^{Y_k} \mathbf{1}_{\{Y_k \le t\}}]
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty P(N(t)=n) E[e^{Y_k} \mathbf{1}_{\{Y_k \le t\}} \mid N(t) = n]
\\
&= \sum_{n=k}^\infty e^{-\lambda t}\frac{(\lambda t)^k}{k!}
\left(1 + \sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{1}{j!} \prod_{r=0}^{j-1}\frac{k+r}{n+1+r}\right).
\end{align}
Then sum over all $k \ge 1$ and multiply by $e^{-t}$.

Comment: Thanks. Theorem $1.5$ says that, conditioned on $N(t)=n$, the joint density function of the $n$ arrival times is the same as the joint density of the $n$ order statistics of $U(0,1)$ variables. But I think what you've used is that the conditional distribution of one of the $Y_k$ variables is Beta which I think is not true because as per the link the distribution of a particular order statistic is Beta.

Comment: @Garfield I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Conditioned on $N(t)=n$, the result is $(Y_1, \ldots, Y_n) \overset{d}{=} (U_{(1)}, \ldots, U_{(n)})$, which implies $Y_k \overset{d}{=} U_{(k)}$.

Comment: You are right...

Comment: May I know how you got $(1)$?

Comment: @Garfield $E[e^{Y_k} \mid N(t)=n]$ is the MGF of the $\text{Beta}(k, n+1-k)$ distribution evaluated at $1$. The expression comes from writing down the MGF (e.g., from the link just above (1)).